# Upgrade Shiro to 1.6.0 fails on duplicate EHCache

Tags: java, spring, ehcache, shiro

I try to upgrade Shiro in a spring web application from 1.2.3 to 1.6.0. I have just modified the version
in gradle and recompiled the war. But it does not start:

```
Caused by: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Another unnamed CacheManager already exists in the same VM.     Please provide unique names for each CacheManager in the config or do one of following:
1. Use one of the CacheManager.create() static factory methods to reuse same CacheManager with same name or create one if necessary
2. Shutdown the earlier cacheManager before creating new one with same name.
The source of the existing CacheManager is: DefaultConfigurationSource [ ehcache.xml or ehcache-failsafe.xml ]
at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.assertNoCacheManagerExistsWithSameName(CacheManager.java:529)
```

I do not use EHCache in Shiro configuration:

```
<import resource="file:${CONFIG_PATH}/ldap-realm.xml"/>

<!-- SHIRO  Access control -->
<bean id="securityManager" class="com.cgi.apps.centaur.engine.access.realm.IPOverridingSecurityManager">
    <property name="realms" ref="shiroRealms"/>
    <property name="cacheManager" ref="memoryConstrainedCacheManager"/>
    <property name="sessionManager" ref="sessionManager"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionManager" class="com.cgi.apps.centaur.engine.access.realm.IPOverridingSessionManager">
</bean>

<bean id="memoryConstrainedCacheManager" class="org.apache.shiro.cache.MemoryConstrainedCacheManager"/>
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Run `mvn dependency:tree` (or the gradle equivalent), this will help you figure out where the ehcache dependency is getting added.  Including the full stacktrace of the error, you are seeing would help too.  Right now there isn't a lot of detail to go on.

Comment: Yes there is. In my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had to explicitely select the packages in gradle. Shiro all imported ehcache module with its own bundled `ehcache.xml` that was conflicting with my config.

```
compile("org.apache.shiro:shiro-core:${versionShiro}") {
    exclude group: 'org.sonatype.sisu.inject', module: 'cglib'
}
compile "org.apache.shiro:shiro-web:${versionShiro}", "org.apache.shiro:shiro-spring:${versionShiro}"
```